# Which JVM language doesn't have type erasure?

Tags: java, scala, clojure, jvm

I'm looking for a JVM-based language that always "remember" types in runtime unless:

1. the compiler has figure out that erasure won't break execution or is irrelevant to the workflow
2. user manually declare a type to be erased.

So far I've only tried scala, which only disable type erasure if declared in source code, this is not what I want as it takes a lot of boilerplates code to implement, and current implementation still has lots of problems (e.g. in Scala, typetags are strictly invariant, prohibiting it from being used in covariant or contravariant situation).

Does this language exist?

Comment: I don't think there are any yet. The natural way to preserve generics would be by storing them within annotations, but there are a lot of things that can't be annotated (or at least couldn't until Java 8), so until very recently, that wouldn't have worked. Note that most types *are* preserved at runtime. Dynamic method dispatch wouldn't work otherwise. Really, what *isn't* preserved are type arguments to type constructors. Which some might argue is as it should be. E.g. Haskell compilers generally erase *all* types (not just generics), and Haskell isn't exactly known to be loose in typing.

Comment: Kotlin has reified generics in inlined functions. So only in some limited cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ceylon has [fully reified generics](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/generics/#fully_reified_generic_types). I haven't tried it myself and don't know how well it works in practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hope I can learn it fast